# How to read all contents inside a file with UTF-8 in Python?

Tags: python, file, utf-8

I want to read all contents inside a file and print them into console but `print(open('file.txt',mode='r').read())` code outputs `€â–` instead of █, ▓, ░ characters and I don't want it. I need to print █, ▓, ░ characters. Is there a way to output all UTF-8 characters correctly?

Comment: `open(..., encoding='utf-8')`…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the encoding in your open-call like this ,encoding='utf-8' in your read(). This way to tell python which encoding is used for the file.

In the end you would have something like this
print(open('file.txt',mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read())